# using Fibonacci numbers prove that if $d|n$ then $F_d|F_n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

The first question was to prove that $\gcd(F_{n+1},F_n) = 1$
So i tried to use it but with no success.
any help or clue will appreciated
thanks

Comment: ralated : [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60340/fibonacci-modular-results) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314507/why-does-cassinis-identity-imply-consecutive-fibonaccis-number-are-relatively)